# "PentesterLab" Like custom linux distro creation for research

Tags: linux

Before I type this post I really did a lot of research on line in order to find "how" to create something like "PentesterLab" custom distro, for my research.

https://pentesterlab.com/exercises/

It simply has interesting guided lessons for basic penetration testing with really amazing and well designed exercises presented in custom linux distro that only contain "boot" and the vulnerable webpages.

So I only lunch the very light live CD (60 MB) sometimes (200MB) and start the practice.

For my research I really want to create something custom like this, that contains only (webserver that contain the vulnerable sites + firewall), and that's pretty much it.
Then I start doing my tests, simple and straight forward.

Is there any simple method to accomplish this task with detailed tutorials ?

But please something other than LFS(Linux from scratch), I's only to configure a small distro that contain webserver and IDS or Firewall for research testing purposes.

Thanks alot,

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions.  You'll probably get better answers on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into something like Docker? There are already some images there that might fit what you are looking for, but you should be able to roll your own with a minimal amount of fuss. And as a bonus you don't need to actually have a dedicated computer available for it, it can easily run one or more instances on your own or a dedicated computer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use debian live, that's what Pentesterlab used to do. It's a lot of messing around to get it working but it works. It also produces big ISO.

Comment: Very helpful tip,
I still have to look how to do  it though.
Thanks